# Preparing for exam: recognizing functions in Set Theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

I'm reviewing earlier exams and found this question:

```
Which of the following relations are functions and which are not?
i.   { <x,y> : x is mother of y},
ii.  { <x,y> : x has as mother y},
iii. { <x,y> : x has as uncle y},
iv.  { <x,y> : x has as lawful partner (m/f) y}.
```

As far as I can tell, they are all functions because they take inputs  and produce something, a relationship, based on these inputs. Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that a function is a relation which has the following property:

> If $\langle x,y\rangle,\langle x,z\rangle$ are in the relation, then $y=z$.

For example, the first example. My mother has three children. Can this be a function?

Comment: Oh, okay. None of them are functions, they are just statements. To become functions, something must be done with the statements, other than just stating them. Yes?

Comment: Also no. You are give relations. Sets of ordered pairs. These sets are defined using a formula (not in a formal language, though). How many mothers can someone have? Does that mean that the relation in the second example is a function or not?

Comment: An equivalent way to describe this is to say that each set of ordered pairs is a function if the first entry of a pair gives all the information needed to determine the second entry.  So look at the first case. Suppose you know the first entry of an ordered pair (the $x$ in an $<x,y>$ pair).  You also know that $x$ is the mother of $y$.  Does this give you enough information to figure out $y$?